# Is it possible to use JWE (json web encryption) with Progress Openedge?

Tags: encryption, openedge, progress-4gl, jwe

Is it possible to use json web encryption with Progress Openedge?

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently supported:

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Support-for-JSON-Web-Encryption-JWE-tokens-in-PASOE

https://openedge.ideas.aha.io/ideas/OPENEDGE-I-718

I suggest you vote for this feature request.

Comment: that's a pitty are their any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

JWE tokens were added in PI 2020.3 and you can generate them with `oesectool` in [Progress OpenEdge 12.5](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-whats-new/page/Whats-New-in-OpenEdge-12.5.html).

Actual support of JWE was **planned** for 12.5, released in an early access build, but then **retracted** in December 2021.